# Visual Studio keeps pegging the CPU for Intellisense as I type

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, linq-to-sql

Why would Visual Studio all of a sudden start using tons of CPU as it tries to implement Intellisense? I happen to be working with LINQ queries in VB.NET, but no idea if that's related or not. I've tried closing and reopening VS, but that has no effect. I'm not sure what else it might be related to, which makes researching it difficult as well. Any ideas where to start looking?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I've had this start happening to me today on my long-standing project which uses WPF and LINQ to SQL, which I don't think I've seen before. Intellisense isn't suggesting anything, but the VS UI is sluggish and it's using 25% average of the CPU of each my four cores. With other projects, including one that is just a code branch of the same project, it is not doing it. Oh, and it finally seems to have stopped, after maybe 20 minutes of grinding.

Answer (score 1):

How about this for a starting place. Check out "C:\Documents and Settings\<userName>\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<versionNumber>". I suggest making a backup then clearing out the folders. There are also folders in `Local Settings`, but I believe these are user-interface related, such as tool box items.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using WIX projects at all? I have had a problem with Wix setup projects causing pegged CPU after opening them.